# How to reset run Scheme process from invalid state

Tags: process, scheme

I use Scheme in Emacs, and the process crashed. I killed the buffer and now I'm in a state like this. When I run the scheme again, it shows this inside the buffer:

```
This is the Scheme process buffer.
Type C-x C-e to evaluate the expression before point.
Type C-c C-c to abort evaluation.
Type C-h m for more information.
```

and there is no prompt from my interpreter. Pressing backspace just delete that text.

I can evaluate code from my scheme buffer:

```
(write '(1 2 3))
(newline)
```

It prints the list and prompt, but I still can press backspace to remove the text. And it only works if I use print statement, it doesn't show expressions.

I also get this message when I run <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>:

> xscheme-process-filter: Symbol’s value as variable is void: xscheme-last-input-end

I execute this function to run Scheme:

```lisp
(defun lips ()
  (interactive)
  (run-scheme "/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/scheme/lips/bin/lips.js -q"))
```

This is my own Scheme interpreter which use ANSI escape codes for syntax highlighting. It works when I have a fresh Emacs session.

I was trying to execute guile:

```lisp
(defun guile ()
  "call run-scheme with guile interpreter."
  (interactive)
  (run-scheme "/usr/bin/guile"))
```

It doesn't look the same as in a fresh session. The modeline says:

> [(Scheme Interaction: ws hl-s)]

When I run a new session I get this Modeline:

> (inferior Scheme:run ws hl-s)

How to restore my Scheme process without opening a new Emacs session?

I've tried to call `interior-scheme-mode` but it only changes the modeline I can't press enter and backspace removes the text from the buffer (including the prompt).

I can run `comint-mode` and I'm able to use the REPL, but I just want my default Scheme interpreter.

Comment: The square brackets in the modeline indicate a recursive editing level: see [Recursive Editing Levels](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recursive-Edit.html) in the Emacs manual. To exit a recursive editing level, see [Quitting and Aborting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html) - the last few paragraphs of the page describe various ways to do that in various circumstances.

Comment: @NickD I'm not able to do anything if I kill the buffer and run the scheme again I end up with the same state. I only temporarily quit, and the only change is modeline. When run again I got `(wrong-type-argument sequencep 27)`. Maybe I need to quit in different way. I just run `C-x k`